# Flip stop on mouseout

Tags: jquery, hover, flip, mouseout

I'm using jQuery flip, and I want to stop the flip when I hover, and reverse it when I mouseout and stop it and if I keep my mouse on it keep stop too...

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.sponsorFlip').hover(function(){

    var elem = $(this);

        elem.flip({
            direction:'bt',
            speed: 350,
            onBefore: function(){

                elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
            }

        });

  }, function() {$(this).revertFlip();});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sponsorFlip').mouseover(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.flip({
      direction:'bt',
      speed: 350,
      onBefore: function(){
        elem.html(elem.siblings('.sponsorData').html());
      }
     });

  }).mouseout(function() {$(this).revertFlip();});
```